# Grep filtering output from a process after it has already started?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe

Normally when one wants to look at specific output lines from running something, one can do something like:

```
./a.out | grep IHaveThisString
```

but what if IHaveThisString is something which changes every time so you need to first run it, watch the output to catch what IHaveThisString is on that particular run, and then grep it out? I can just dump to file and later grep but is it possible to do something like background it and then bring it to foreground and bringing it back but now piped to some grep? Something akin to:

```
./a.out
Ctrl-Z
fg | grep NowIKnowThisString
```

just wondering..

Comment: Did you try with using `./a.out > some_file` and later doing `tail -f some_file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short form: You can do this, but you need to *know* that you need to do it ahead-of-time; it's not something that can be put into place interactively after-the-fact.

---

Write your script to determine what the string is. We'd need a more detailed example of the output format to give a better example of usage, but here's one for the trivial case where the entire first line is the filter target:

```
run_my_command | { read string_to_filter_for; fgrep -e "$string_to_filter_for" }
```

Replace the `read string_to_filter_for` with as many commands as necessary to read enough input to determine what the target string is; this could be a loop if necessary.

For instance, let's say that the output contains the following:

```
Session id: foobar
```

and thereafter, you want to grep for lines containing `foobar`.

...then you can pipe through the following script:

```
re='Session id: (.*)'
while read; do
  if [[ $REPLY =~ $re ]] ; then
    target=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    break
  else
    # if you want to print the preamble; leave this out otherwise
    printf '%s\n' "$REPLY" 
  fi
done
[[ $target ]] && grep -F -e "$target"
```

If you want to manually specify the filter target, this can be done by having the loop check for a file being created with filter contents, and using *that* when starting up grep afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is only in your screen buffer if you didn't save it in some other way.

Comment: I'd think that a mechanism for "saving it some other way" would be a legitimate part of the question.

Comment: on some terminal emulators, you can start a trace at any time. That is another approach, but then it has nothing to do with the session itself.

Answer (score 1):

That is a little bit strange what you need, but you can do it tis way:

- you must go into `script` session first;
- then you use shell how usually;
- then you start and interrupt you program;
- then run `grep` over `typescript` file.

Example:

```
$ script
$ ./a.out
Ctrl-Z
$ fg 
$ grep NowIKnowThisString typescript
```

Comment: As I understand the question, the goal is for the grep to be part of a pipeline -- thus, ongoing as new output is generated, rather than over a static file only after output is complete. What's given here won't continue to send new contents through grep after content already there is exhausted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: No, Charles, you are not right. You run the process in foreground, that means that you start `grep` after the process is already finished. The only point (as far as I understood) that you want to start the process without `grep` and when you see something interesting in the output, you want to `grep` it.

Comment: I can't agree with that interpretation. The stated goal is to be able to "bring the process back to foreground" with its output now filtered. If it's in the foreground, obviously it's intended to still be running and generating new output at this time. That makes what we're trying to accomplish difficult -- but not impossible.

Comment: after fg, you can't attach a pipe to it at this point. So it just runs off at the terminal.

Comment: @pizza Quite right -- but it *is* possible to pipe into something that's configured to change its behavior during runtime.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: In this case I found the solution from h3nr1x (tail -f) the best one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right on. The application has to be designed to accept a signal and then modify its behaviour, it is possible. Just not in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stream editor such as `sed` instead of `grep`. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
$ cat list 
Name to look for: Mike

Dora 1
John 2
Mike 3
Helen 4
```

Here we find the name to look for in the fist line and want to `grep` for it. Now piping the command to `sed`:

```
$ cat list | sed -ne '1{s/Name to look for: //;h}' \
> -e ':r;n;G;/^.*\(.\+\).*\n\1$/P;s/\n.*//;br'
Mike 3
```

Note: `sed` itself can take file as a parameter, but you're not working with text files, so that's how you'd use it.

Of course, you'd need to modify the command for your case.